# Primefaces' captcha always fails

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

since yesterday (March 18th 2015) my Primefaces' captcha always fails even if I send the correct anwser.

Please find below my configuration

In my **xhtml** (inside a form):

```
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column style="width: 25em">
                            <p:outputLabel value="Codice di sicurezza" for="captcha" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:captcha label="Verifica" required="true" language="it" theme="clean" secure="true" id="captcha" 
                                requiredMessage='#{messagesRetrieverService.searchByJSONCode("002008","{\"nomeCampo\":\"Verifica utente\"}")}' />
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
```

In my **web.xml**:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.PRIVATE_CAPTCHA_KEY</param-name>
    <param-value>[my key is a secret]</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.PUBLIC_CAPTCHA_KEY</param-name>
    <param-value>6LcJxAMTAAAAAAqgxuBQmHarl2M5RqBuisd_sWxP</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I've already checked that the Google service is online.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the "onclick" event used by the button to refresh the captcha.
I have to use instead "oncomplete" to avoid the refreshing of the captcha value prior to the action listener.

You can find below my "new" commandButton:

```
<p:commandButton id="buttonRichiedi" value="Invia la richiesta" actionListener="#{richiediUtenzaCtr.doAction('ricerca')}"  oncomplete="Recaptcha.reload()" 
                        disabled="#{richiediUtenzaModel.disableRichiestaUtenza}" update=":dialogSceltaCompagniaId :growlForm:growl buttonPanel panelDati"/>
```